# I need to build a matrix in R from data gathered using Google Map. I try but always get an error message

Tags: arrays, r, google-maps

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
m<-NULL
z<-NULL
Latitud<-seq(10.7271159059,10.8179459002, length=25)
Longitud<-seq(-64.0062194193,-63.8733323054, length=25)
for (i in 1:25)  {
  m<-cbind(m,Longitud=rep(Longitud[i],25),Latitud, deparse.level=1)
}

googElh <- function(locs)  {
  require(RJSONIO)
  locstring <- paste(do.call(paste, list(locs[, 2], locs[, 1], sep=',')),
                     collapse='|')
  u <- sprintf('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=%s&sensor=false',
               locstring)
  res <- fromJSON(u)
  out <- t(sapply(res[[1]], function(x) {
    c(x['elevation']) 
  }))    
  rownames(out) <- rownames(locs)
  return(out)
}

Alturas<-array(0, dim=c(25,25))

for (i in 1:25)  {
  P<-data.frame(googElh(m[,c(2*i-1,2*i)]))
  for (k in 1:25) {
    if (P$elevation[k]<0) {
      P$elevation[k]<-0
    }
    Alturas[i,k]<-P$elevation[k]
  }
}
```

> Error: el objeto (list) no puede ser coercionado a 'double'

Comment: Please format your question to make it easier for us to read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # This should work, I say should because by the time i figured it out, I hit 
 # my API data allowance; just edit the loop after you make the null matrix, 
 # Alturas

 Alturas <-matrix(data=NA,nrow=25,ncol=25)
 for (i in 1:25)  {
   for (k in 1:25) {
     P<-data.frame(googElh(m[,c(2*i-1,2*i)]))
     P[P<0] <- 0
     Alturas[i,k]<-unlist(P[k])
   }
 }
Alturas
```